# Twython returns less retweets than retweets shown on tweet

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twython, twitterapi-python

So I am using Twython to get retweeters of a tweet

```
 tweet = self.twitter.show_status(id=tweet_id)
 if tweet.get('retweet_count') > 0:
        try:
            retweets = self.twitter.get_retweets(id=tweet.get("id"))
        except TwythonRateLimitError:
            self.twitter, self.Last_Acc_Id = self.switch_accounts(MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            self.get_retweeters(tweet)

        # pprint(f"RETWEETS: {retweets}")
        print(f"RETWEET COUNT: {len(retweets)}")
        screen_name_list = []
        for retweet in retweets:
            # print(retweet)
            # print()
            # print(dir(retweet))
            screen_name = retweet["user"]["screen_name"]
            print(screen_name, f"https://twitter.com/{screen_name}/")
            screen_name_list.append(screen_name)
```

But it returns only 20 retweets where as the tweet has 350 retweets
[Tweet](https://twitter.com/Animetas1/status/1424897472065904640)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation "get_retweets" returns "up to" the first 100 retweeters of a tweet.
[-> Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id)

You can specify the amount of entries per request with a parameter "count=100". Furthermore to iterate through multiple requests you should use a [cursor (Twython API Docs)](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/special_functions.html#the-new-way).

I confirmed with the library source code that this endpoint is used.
[-> Library Code](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/endpoints.py#L77-L85)

Depending of your usecase you should consider using the [Webhook API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api/guides/getting-started-with-webhooks)

If the webhook API does not fit your use case, you should reconsider if you only need the retweet **count** or the **retweeters**.

The retweet count can simply be requested via [GET statuses/show/:id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id). Look at "retweeted_count".

This is also available in Twython: [show_status](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/endpoints.py#L87-L94).

I hope this helped you! :)

Comment: I wanted retweeters username with their following and followers count 
And thanks for clarifying it but the problem remains